# Is it ok to change directly the state if we don't want to re-render?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have this state:

```
this.state = {name: "Bernard"};
```

I want to change it but I don't want to re-render. Is it okay to not use `this.setState(...)` and do that instead?

```
this.state.name = "Claude";
```

Thank you for your help.

---

The reason why I don't want to re-render is because I did a two-way binding on an `<input>`:

```
handleChange(evt) {
  const name = evt.target.value;
  this.setState({name: name});
}

render() {
  ...
  <input value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  ...
}
```

But when I do that, each time I change the value of the input, the state is changed so the template is re-rendered and the focus on the input is moved to the left.

I know that this problem could be solved if I stopped the binding from the state to the UI like that `<input onChange={handleChange} />`, but I absolutely want a two-way binding.

Comment: This feels suspicious. I don't think I've ever seen React behave this way (stealing focus like that): https://codesandbox.io/s/xol4rk773z

Comment: In fact I used a `contenteditable` span and used the `input` event, I don't know if we get this problem like this, but I used an `input` tag for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do this, I would recommend looking at the other lifecycle methods here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

For example, `shouldComponentUpdate()`, which factors in a boolean value which **may** prevent re-rendering:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextState.name != this.state.name)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```